# Pillow broke - hash collision: : 22 for both 1 and 1

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, hash-collision

My Pillow installation is broken system-wide.

Either using my OS X pillow version, or other 'isolated' installations within anaconda environments, I always get the same error, while trying to process images:

```
AccessInit: hash collision: 22 for both 1 and 1
```

It used to work in the envs, but after some `urllib` installs it broke in the environments also.

I have tried, at the top of my script (to no avail):

```
import PIL.Image
sys.modules['Image'] = PIL.Image
from PIL import Image
```

I have already uninstalled an reinstalled Pillow, again to no avail.

my Python:

```
Python 2.7.14 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Oct  5 2017, 02:28:52) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

How can I make it work again?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is likely that two different Python modules are being imported with the same name - https://web.archive.org/web/20110121072135/https://jaredforsyth.com/blog/2010/apr/28/accessinit-hash-collision-3-both-1-and-1/

Without having access to your installation, it is hard to figure out exactly what is happening, so I would suggest tracking each import. A good start would be to see what is imported.

```
import sys
sys.modules
```

That, combined with going into the site-packages directory of your Python install and manually removing packages until you find the problematic package, will hopefully give you a good start.